# Disable all action on click except within parent

Tags: jquery

I need to disable all click action when a certain element is visible, except the elements within the parent of the visible element.

Can I do something like this?

```
if ($(".myEm").is(":visible")) {
    $("*").not($(".myEm:visible").parent().find("button").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: where is `$(this)` coming from? can you show the full code?

Comment: @atmd Good point. I don't really have more code, but you're right, I have not defined $(this)...